# EKEventStore Change Notifications Not Firing when app in Background

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, ekeventstore

I have registered for Calendar Change Notifications using the following:

```
- (void) registerForLocalCalendarChanges
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(localCalendarStoreChanged) name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification object:self.store     ];
}
```

This should call the following when a change is made to the local calendar:

```
- (void) localCalendarStoreChanged
{
// This gets called when an event in store changes
// you have to go through the calendar to look for changes
// launch this in a thread of its own!
ashsysCalendarEventReporter *eventReport = [ashsysCalendarEventReporter new];

NSLog(@"Local Calendar Store Changed");

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getCalendarEvents) toTarget:eventReport withObject:nil];
}
```

BUT...when I start the app, then send it to the background so I can change a calendar entry, nothing happens when I change the calendar entry.  It DOES fire when I return to the app.  But, of course that is not the objective.

store is defined in the header file with:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) EKEventStore *store;
```

Update...forgot to show the stuff I have in the background fetch.

This is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
```

This is in the app delegate:

```
 - (void) application:(UIApplication*) application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^) (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
//    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier uploadCalInfo = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
NSLog(@"A fetch got called");
//    ashsysCalendarEventReporter *eventReport = [ashsysCalendarEventReporter new];
//    [eventReport getCalendarEvents];
//    // [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getCalendarEvents) toTarget:eventReport withObject:nil];
//    [application endBackgroundTask:uploadCalInfo];
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
```

The performFetch gets called at what seem like random times some not at all related to the calendar.  Is there a way to find out what is firing the background fetch?  Is it always the calendar?  The actual execution is commented out -- is it correct?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find this answer out myself and I don't think there's an actual way to accomplish this. [As per Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW47), we're not allowed access to system resources while in a background state:

> Stop using shared system resources before being suspended. Apps that interact with shared system resources such as the Address Book or calendar databases should stop using those resources before being suspended. Priority for such resources always goes to the foreground app. When your app is suspended, if it is found to be using a shared resource, the app is killed.

I'm still looking for a better answer/work around but would love to hear this from anyone else.